# Proposition 22.3 Brian Hall - Quantum Theory for Mathematicians

Tags: geometry, symplectic-geometry

I've been reading Brian Hall Quantum Theory for Mathematicians and I'm struggling with the proof of proposition 22.3. Specifically, how equation (22.5) comes about:

i.e. want to prove $[\nabla_{X},\nabla_{Y}]-\nabla_{[X,Y]}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}X(\theta(Y))-Y(\theta(X))-\theta([X,Y]))$ for $\nabla_{X}=X-\frac{i}{\hbar}\theta(X)$ and $\theta$ any symplectic potential.

This is my attempt:

$[\nabla_{X},\nabla_{Y}]-\nabla_{[X,Y]}=[X-k\theta(X),Y-k\theta(Y)]-[X,Y]+k\theta([X,Y])\\
=[X,Y]-k[X,\theta(Y)]-k[\theta(X),Y]+k^{2}[\theta(X),\theta(Y)]-[X,Y]+k\theta([X,Y])\\
=-kX(\theta(Y))-k\theta(Y)\cdot X-k\theta(X)\cdot Y+kY(\theta(X))+k\theta([X,Y])$

where $k=\frac{i}{\hbar}$.

So I have the three terms I want but also two extra which I don't see how they'd cancel. I feel like I am probably missing something obvious.

I've attached a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRUm1.png) if my description isn't clear.

Thank you for any help, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\theta(Y)$ term in the covariant derivative means multiplication by the function $\theta(Y)$. So for any function $\psi$
$$
[X,\theta(Y)]\psi = X(\theta(Y)\psi) - \theta(Y)(X\psi) = X(\theta(Y))\psi + \theta(Y)(X\psi) - \theta(Y)(X\psi) 
= X(\theta(Y))\psi,
$$
where I have used the Leibniz property $X(fg) = f(Xg) + g(Xf)$ for functions $f,g$ in the second step. In other words
$$[X,\theta(Y)] = X(\theta(Y)),$$ not $X(\theta(Y)) + \theta(Y)\cdot X$ as you write above. This explains your two additional terms.